# Rename a file with FileSystemObject while looping through files

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003, ms-access-2013

As a preface, I'm writing code in Access 2003, but will have users using Access 2013, and so I need it to be compatible for both.  I have a loop that uses the Application.FileSearch to loop through a number of files in a directory.  It is my understanding that this is deprecated in newer version of Access, and so I have to use "For Each" to loop through files.

Here's the piece of code I'm changing:

```
strPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Files\"

strFileName = "SourceCode.txt"

With Application.FileSearch
    .FileName = "*.txt"
    .LookIn = strPath
    .Execute
    intFileCount = .foundfiles.Count
    For x = 1 To intFileCount
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set f = fs.GetFile(.foundfiles(x))
        strNewFileName = Right((.foundfiles(x)), Len((.foundfiles(x))) - (InStr((.foundfiles(x)), "Files\") + 5))
        fs.MoveFile f, strPath & strFileName
        'Run the Process() function
        Process
        FileCopy strPath & strFileName, strPath & "Processed\" & strNewFileName
        Kill strPath & strFileName
    Next x
End With
```

And here's the code I'm replacing it with:

```
strPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Files\"

strFileName = "SourceCode.txt"

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fs.GetFolder(strPath)
Set fc = f.Files

For Each f1 In fc
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strPath & f1.Name, 1)
    strNewFileName = f1.Name
    f1.Name = strFileName
    'Run the Process() function
    Process
    FileCopy strPath & strFileName, strPath & "Processed\" & strNewFileName
    Kill strPath & strFileName
Next
```

This code loops through each file, then launches a Process() function that makes changes to the file.  So the way I have it working is it changes the active file to be named "SourceCode.txt", then the Process() function knows to work with the file of that name.  Then it moves the file to the "Processed" subfolder, with its original file name.

This worked fine in the original code.  The new code seems to mostly work, except I can't find a way to rename the file to "SourceCode.txt" prior to launching Process().  I tried several ways but I keep getting errors.  In the code above, I tried "f1.Name = strFileName".  This gives me a "Permission Denied" error.  I tried alternatively to use FileCopy, and then the Kill command on the original file, but the Kill command returned an error.  I suspect the FileSystemObject is locking the file so it can't be moved or killed.  But the old version of the code was able to move it with no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get "Permission Denied" because you are attempting to rename a file when it is in use, namely by `objFSO.OpenTextFile`.  This is different than `fs.GetFile` and not in your original code - do you need it?  It returns a `TextStream` that you are not subsequently using.

In any event, move the `f1.Name = strFileName` to before opening the file, or after you are done processing, call `objFile.Close` and then rename.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I didn't need to open the file in this function. I think I grabbed sample code somewhere to model the 'For Each' loop and that piece was in it. Removing it solved the problem.  Thanks!